# Retrieve Date Column from SQLite Using Android Cursor db.query

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

How do I retrieve rows containing SQLite TIMESTAMP columns and cast those columns to Java Date type parameters in Android.

I want to retrieve rows from a SQLite Database using Android cursor db.query, here is the Table definition

```
private final static String TABLE_NAME = "custTable";
private final static String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
private final static String COLUMN_NAME = "name";
private final static String COLUMN_EMAIL = "email";
private final static String COLUMN_PHONE = "phone";
private final static String COLUMN_UID = "card_uid2";
private final static String COLUMN_INITIAL_VALUE = "initial_value";
private final static String COLUMN_CURRENT_VALUE = "current_value";
private final static String COLUMN_DATE_CREATED = "enrollment_date";
private final static String COLUMN_LAST_UPDATED = "last_transaction_date";
```

Here is my cursor db.query statement

```
Cursor cursor = database.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[]{ COLUMN_ID,COLUMN_NAME,COLUMN_EMAIL, COLUMN_PHONE +
                 COLUMN_UID, COLUMN_INITIAL_VALUE, COLUMN_CURRENT_VALUE,COLUMN_DATE_CREATED,COLUMN_LAST_UPDATED}, null, null, null, null, null);
```

If I do this how do I cast or convert my two SQLite Timestamp columns to Java Date parameters. After many tries, I then tried to use cursor db.rawquery like so

```
Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(
                "SELECT _id, name, email, phone, card_uid2, initial_value, current value," +
                 " (strftime('%s', enrollment_date) * 1000) AS enrollment_date, " +
                 " (strftime('%s', last_transaction_date) * 1000) AS last_transaction_date, +" +
                 "FROM  custTable", new String[0]);
```

With the db.rawquery option, I proceeded to change to Java Date parameter like to

```
        long millis_enrolled = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("enrollment_date"));
        Date enrolledDate = new Date(millis_enrolled);
        customer.setEnrollmentDate(enrolledDate);

        long millis_updated = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("last_transaction_date"));
        Date updatedDate = new Date(millis_updated);
        customer.setEnrollmentDate(updatedDate);
```

Either way, when I try to access these value in my Activity I get a Java NullPointerException like so

```
05-08 15:52:45.484: W/dalvikvm(1950): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb1f07648)
05-08 15:52:45.484: E/AndroidRuntime(1950): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-08 15:52:45.484: E/AndroidRuntime(1950): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.txsystems.valuecard/com.txsystems.valuecard.app.ReportActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-08 15:52:45.484: E/AndroidRuntime(1950):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
05-08 15:52:45.484: E/AndroidRuntime(1950):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
05-08 15:52:45.484: E/AndroidRuntime(1950):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
05-08 15:52:45.484: E/AndroidRuntime(1950):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
05-08 15:52:45.484: E/AndroidRuntime(1950):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-08 15:52:45.484: E/AndroidRuntime(1950):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-08 15:52:45.484: E/AndroidRuntime(1950):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
05-08 15:52:45.484: E/AndroidRuntime(1950):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
```

So my question again is how do I retrieve rows containing SQLite TIMESTAMP columns and cast those columns to Java Date type parameters.

Here is the Create Table Statement

```
private static final String CREATE_CUSTOMER_TABLE =
                "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "(" +
                COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "  +
                COLUMN_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                COLUMN_EMAIL + " TEXT, " +
                COLUMN_PHONE + " TEXT, " +
                COLUMN_UID + " TEXT, " +
                COLUMN_DATE_CREATED + " TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp, " +
                COLUMN_LAST_UPDATED + " TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp, " +
                COLUMN_INITIAL_VALUE + " NUMERIC, " +
                COLUMN_CURRENT_VALUE + " NUMERIC " +
                ")";
```

More Logcat output

```
05-08 17:12:46.857: I/Enrollment(2398): Calling the GetAll Customers method
05-08 17:12:46.857: I/Enrollment(2398): Inside getAllCustomer function
05-08 17:12:46.857: D/AndroidRuntime(2398): Shutting down VM
05-08 17:12:46.857: W/dalvikvm(2398): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb1f07648)
05-08 17:12:46.857: E/AndroidRuntime(2398): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-08 17:12:46.857: E/AndroidRuntime(2398): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.txsystems.valuecard/com.txsystems.valuecard.app.ReportActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-08 17:12:46.857: E/AndroidRuntime(2398):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
```

Comment: i suggest you look at the complete stacktrace and see where the NPE is.

Comment: I think we need to see the create table statement.  I don't think there is a timestamp datatype just functions for date manipulation.

Comment: I have added the create table statement and I can verify using sqlite3 command that table is created and I am writing data to the table.

Comment: can u point the line where u are getting NPE ?

Comment: Added more Logcat output showing the NPE, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Problem was that the database is not open before I tried to use it in the Activity, so I placed a call to `db.getwritableDatabase()` right before I made the first db query.